# Call another function within same EJS file

Tags: javascript, ejs, mountebank

I was trying to call another function which is in same ejs file.

```
async function (request, state, logger) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var util = require('util');
    var response;
    var RspFilename = "my-success.xml";
    var responsepath = path.join('ConfigFiles', 'Responses', 'ABS', RspFilename);
    response = fs.readFileSync((responsepath), 'utf8');

    await this.sleep(1000);
    return {
        headers: {
            "HTTP-Response-Code": 200,
            "HTTP-Response-Code-Text": "OK",
            "Content-Type": "text/xml"
        },
        "statusCode": "200",
        body: response
    };
}


function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

I am trying this mountebank. When call the endpoint I get below error though

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "invalid injection",
            "message": "invalid response injection",
            "source": "(async function (request, state, logger) {\n    var fs = require('fs');\n    var path = require('path');\n    var util = require('util');\n    var response;\n    var RspFilename = \"my-success.xml\";\n    var responsepath = path.join('ConfigFiles', 'Responses', 'ABS', RspFilename);\n    response = fs.readFileSync((responsepath), 'utf8');\n\n    logger.info(\"---------Response Sent Successfully--------\" + RspFilename + response);\n    await this.sleep(1000);\n    return {\n        headers: {\n            \"HTTP-Response-Code\": 200,\n            \"HTTP-Response-Code-Text\": \"OK\",\n            \"Content-Type\": \"text/xml\"\n        },\n        \"statusCode\": \"200\",\n        body: response\n    };\n}\n\n\nfunction sleep(ms) {\n    return new Promise((resolve) => {\n        setTimeout(resolve, ms);\n    });\n})(scope, injectState, logger, deferred.resolve, imposterState);",
            "data": "Unexpected token function",
            "name": "Error",
            "stack": "Error\n    at Object.from (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\util\\inherit.js:15:17)\n    at createError (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\util\\errors.js:10:26)\n    at Object.InjectionError (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\util\\errors.js:25:16)\n    at inject (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\models\\responseResolver.js:43:44)\n    at processResponse (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\models\\responseResolver.js:243:20)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\models\\responseResolver.js:277:16)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\models\\stubRepository.js:136:25)\n    at F.respond (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\models\\http\\baseHttpServer.js:94:34)\n    at C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\src\\models\\abstractServer.js:105:39\n    at _fulfilled (C:\\Repo\\mountebank\\node_modules\\q\\q.js:854:54)"
        }
    ]
}
```

Actually my requirement is to add some delay for the response.

BTW I tried [Mountebank wait](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/behaviors#behavior-wait), but couldn't see any delay.

Comment: I've never used mountebank, but `sleep` has been declared in scope of that file, hasn't it? Can't you just call `sleep(1000)` without `this`?

Comment: @DustInCompetent I tried `await sleep(1000); ` same result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the code examples on http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/injection, It seems, mountebank doesn't expect anything to follow the single anonymous function, hence "Unexpected token function" when it starts reading `function sleep`.

Try moving `sleep` into the other function. Not far off, since you've already done the same with module imports:

```js
async function (request, state, logger) {
    // ...
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    } 

    await sleep(1000);
    // ...
}
```

Or simply

```js
async function (request, state, logger) {
    // ...
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    // ...
}
```

Or, simplifying the whole function

```js
function (request, state, logger) {
    // ...
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
            headers: // ...

        })
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Apparently `this.` is not necessary for the first solution.

Comment: You're right, edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a function but forgot to give it a name on line 1.

If you meant to define an anonymous function rather than make a `async function` *statement*, you need to wrap it in parentheses.

Comment: Tried this as well `(async function (request, state, logger) {
...
    await sleep(10000);
....
        body: response
    };
})();


function sleep(ms) {
    ...
} ` I believe `async` hast be there as we call wait function